# looping html5 video getting black screen after video is playing again in html

Tags: html, css

I have added a code for playing video as a banner but facing one problem in that is whenever the video is completed getting a black screen  for a moment and again the video is playing.

```html
<div class="background-wrap">
  <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" width="100%" height="400"><source src="http://localhost/blue/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/4K_UHD_Drone_Fly_Past_Radio_Tower_Portland_Oregon_Crest_Point_Fernando-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've amended your tag a little to include `autoplay loop` instead of `autoplay="true" loop="loop"`.

I also think you've just got your HTML syntax a little wrong - instead of putting the source in a `<source>` tag, you should include a `src=""` within the `<video>` tag like so:

```html
<div class="background-wrap">
  <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted="muted" width="100%" height="400" src="https://app.coverr.co/s3/mp4/Over-the-Map.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

As you can see there's no black screen at the end of this looping video. If it is still happening on for you with your own material, it might actually be your video that has a slight gap at the end?

Comment: but when placing my video here it is getting black screen

Comment: Sorry the problem was in my video only

Comment: Thought it might be! :-)

Answer (score 3):

**I have tested this in all the browser.** Please take a look to the attributes in this tag and this will also work in your case.

```html
  <video width="400" controls playsinline loop muted >
      <source src="https://app.coverr.co/s3/mp4/Over-the-Map.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

**UPDATE:** newer versions of mobile phone browsers on Android and iOS do support autoplay function. But it only works if the video is muted or has no audio channel. :-)

For more details on the UPDATE section read this: 
https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: In my snippet, use autoplay attr for make this auto play whenever user come to this part. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my html for making my video autoplay and loop with no problems. Give this a try.

```
<video muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```